# ¿Cómo puedo castear objetos de diferentes clases pero con exactamente los mismos atributos?

Tags: java, objeto, class, cast, atributos

Lo que pasa es que tengo clases de diferentes nombres pero con exactamente los mismos atributos y métodos. Lo que pasa es que una viene de una clase request que se generó sola al consumir un Web Service y la otra es de una clase que se generó automáticamente al compilar mi pantalla por otros métodos.

En sí es esto. Tengo una clase llamada Clase1 y una clase llamada Clase2. Ambas clases tienen los mismos atributos y los mismos getters y setter, por ejemplo:

```
    public class Clase1 implements java.io.Serializable
  {
  private java.lang.String variableId;
  private java.lang.String variableNombre;
  //Sus getters y setters
  }

public class Clase2 implements java.io.Serializable
  {
  private java.lang.String variableId;
  private java.lang.String variableNombre;
  //Sus getters y setters
  }
```

Ahora necesito crear un objeto de la Clase1 a partir de los valores de los atributos de la Clase2

Además de este modo (manualmente):

```
    Clase1 obj = new Clase1();
Clase2 obj2 = new Clase2();
obj.setVariableId(obj2.getVariableId);
obj.setVariableNombre(obj2.getVariableNombre);
```

Hay alguna manera de pasarle los valores de un lado a otro en forma de casteo o con algún truco y no de uno por uno? (porque realmente no son 2 atributos, son muchísimos y algunos con arreglo de objetos dentro, etc). Repito, ambas clases están exactamente igual, lo único que las diferencía es el paquete donde se encuentran y el nombre que tienen dichas clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una librería externa con una utilidad para hacer lo que requieres.

Por ejemplo te recomiendo BeanUtils de SpringFramework en donde tendrías algo así:

```
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(obj, obj2);
```

Con esto, se intentarán copiar las propiedades que coincidan desde obj a obj2.

https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-beanutils.html

Comment: El primer valor de copyProperties es el objeto que tiene los valores y el segundo es el objeto al que le va a copiar los valores al parecer. No me funciona u.u

Comment: @user2930137 porqué no funciona? qué error te da? En efecto la firma del método es BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);

Comment: Disculpa, estaba usando un BeanUtils de apache!! Ya funcionó, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te indico tres opciones dos no te van a gustar y la ultima es la ñapa que te servira

- Refactorizar el codigo para solo utilizar la clase que te dan de esa forma no tienes clases duplicadas con un control f y un rename a todo el codigo de una clase a otra te valdrá si son las dos iguales. (**No sé qué editor estás utilizando, pero todos te permiten refactorizar clases y renombrarlas aplicándolo a todo el código con tres clicks**)
- la segunda opción es crearte un método que reciba como parámetro el objeto de la primera clase y lo convierta (es una forma más tediosa y a mí me gusta menos por el código)
- la tercera opción tiene un gasto mayor de recursos y sería transformándolo aún Json ([documentación de conversión](https://medium.com/el-acordeon-del-programador/convertir-objetos-java-a-json-y-de-regreso-1077500d78f7)) para después deserializar lo en el otro objeto